# Save audio to iTunes library

Tags: ios, itunes

Is it possible to save audio files to devices iTunes library programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, Apple does not allow third-party-application accessing anything else than their own data (with a few exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

**No, you cannot.** Due to Apple's sandboxing regulations, 3rd party programs cannot access the inner files of the iPhone.